# How do I compute the summation where k is greater than or equal to $0$ of $\frac{1}{k+1}{99 \choose k}$ ${200 \choose 120-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How do I compute 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{99}{k}\binom{200}{120-k}.
$$

I have expanded it to this:
$$
\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot\frac{99!}{k!(99-k)!}\cdot\frac{200!}{(120-k)!(80+k)!}
$$
but am stuck after that. Is there any way to write my answer as an expression involving one or two binomial coefficients?

Comment: I have edited your post to include typeset math using MathJax. As you can see, it greatly improves readability -- and if you want our help, putting effort in to making it as easy as possible for us seems like a good idea!  See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some basic information about how to do this yourself.

Comment: Unless you compute things differently, there is a problem with $\binom{99}{k}$ for $k>99$, and there is also a problem with $\binom{200}{120-k}$ for $k>120$.

Comment: $n \choose k$ is taken to be $0$ for $k > n$ (integers).

Comment: @RobertIsrael: That is what I assumed (and I even had prior to editing my comment), but I wasn't sure what to do with the negative integers incurred in the second binomial.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Thanks I appreciate that help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that $\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot\frac{99!}{k!(99-k)!}=\frac{1}{100}\cdot\frac{100!}{(k+1)!(100-(k+1))!},$ so you can re-write your sum as:
$$\frac{1}{100}\sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{100}{k+1}\binom{200}{120-k}
=\frac{1}{100}\sum_{k=1}^{100}\binom{100}{k}\binom{200}{121-k}.$$
Now:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom{100}{k}\binom{200}{121-k}=\left[x^{121}\right](1+x)^{100}(1+x)^{200}=\binom{300}{121},$$
so your sum is equal to:
$$\frac{1}{100}\left(\binom{300}{121}-\binom{200}{121}\right).$$